# Are there any online survey/questionnaire makers which allow use of sound clips?

Tags: experiment-design

I am looking to create an online data collection tool which would involve questions where a short sound clip is played, and the respondents would need to use a rating scale (possibly a slider) to respond.

So far I've come across several sites which do not allow uploading sound clips - any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Two such systems include Qualtrics and Inquisit. For example: https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/editing-questions/rich-content-editor/insert-media/